# Copy Only String properties from one object to another

Tags: java, dozer, modelmapper

I was working with dozer and I had a special scenario which I think dozer doesn't support.
Suppose I have a class with different type of properties like String,Ingeger and other primitive types. Now I want to copy only string property from this class to another.
Here s a example code :(Its very brief, but it will give proper understanding of problem.)

```
Class Source{
private int a;
private boolean b;
private String s1;
//more properties with primitive type.

}
Class Destination{
//    same structure
}
```

Now I want somethink like,

```
DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
//    initialize Object of source
//   initialize Object of destination
mapper.map(source,destination);
```

Is it possible with any dozer ? I am familiar with dozer. But Oper to other APIs like apache beanutil or ModelMapper. Feel free to answer in any of this technology.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`populate()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/index.html) and [`setProperty()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/index.html) of [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/).

First `populate()` an empty bean, than, 
you can apply an `if` condition as:

```
if (urBean.getAParameter() instanceof String){
    setProperty(newBeanObject, "propertyName", urBean.getParameter());
}
```